# Dúvida quanto a window.location.href()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Sei que `window.open()` será aberto a `url` em uma nova janela e que o `window.location.href()` será aberta na página chamadora. Acontece que quando eu uso o `window.location.href()`, coloquei no page_load uma chamada javascript(`alert()`) pelo code `behind` e não disparou. Porém, essa página(chamada) gera um `excel` e isso está acontecendo, funcionando perfeitamente. Coloquei um loading nela(no `apsx`) e também não disparou, pois a página parece que é executada em background, não sei se isso é verdade, mas é o que parece, mas mesmo assim os `alerts` deveriam ser disparados ou não?

---

Essa é a função que chama a página que carrega a planilha(Observe as várias tentativas no else que eu fiz e nenhuma funcionou.

```
function AcaoAvancar() {

            if (ValidaFormulario()) {

                var dataInicial = $("#txt_dt_ref_inicial").val();
                var dataFinal = $("#txt_dt_ref_final").val();
                var tipoTabela = $('#ddl_tipotabela option:selected').val();
                var tabelas = RetornaTabelas();
                var classificacoes = RetornaClassificacoes();
                var grupos = RetornaGrupos();
                var autorizacao = $('#ddl_autorizacaoprevia option:selected').val();
                var formato = $("input[name='formato']:checked").val();

                var strOpcao = "dtinicial=" + dataInicial;
                strOpcao = strOpcao + "&dtfinal=" + dataFinal;
                if (tipoTabela != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&tipotab=" + tipoTabela; }
                if (tabelas != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&tabl=" + tabelas; }
                if (classificacoes != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&class=" + classificacoes; }
                if (grupos != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&grp=" + grupos; }
                if (autorizacao != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&aut=" + autorizacao; }
                if (formato != "") { strOpcao = strOpcao + "&format=" + formato; }

                if (formato == "PDF")
                    window.location.href = "../../../hes/asp/hes1015b.asp?" + strOpcao;
                else {

                    window.location.href = '../../relatorios/Rel_ItensMaterialMedicamentoExcel.aspx?' + strOpcao;
                    //window.open('../../relatorios/Rel_ItensMaterialMedicamentoExcel.aspx?' + strOpcao);
                    //document.location.href = '../../relatorios/Rel_ItensMaterialMedicamentoExcel.aspx?' + strOpcao;
                    //$("#carregaLoad").load();
                }
            }
        }
```

Esse é o Page_Load onde são processados os dados do banco para a planilha. Esse código está na página chamada e é ela que está sendo o meu problema. Veja que coloquei umas chamadas a uns alerts e nenhum foi disparado:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            try
            {

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mensagem", "Mensagem()", true);

                //Parametros do filtro
                string dataInicial = Request.QueryString["dtinicial"];
                string dataFinal = Request.QueryString["dtfinal"];
                string tipoTabela = Request.QueryString["tipotab"];
                string tabela = Request.QueryString["tabl"];
                string classificacao = Request.QueryString["class"];
                string grupo = Request.QueryString["grp"];
                string autorizacao = Request.QueryString["aut"];

                //Carregar Lista de objetos RelatorioItensMatMed
                List<RelatorioItensMatMed> listaItensMatMed = (new Rel_ItensMaterialMedicamento_BS()).get_Rel_ItensMatMed_BS(dataInicial, dataFinal, tipoTabela, tabela, classificacao, grupo, autorizacao);

                //Preencher os dados do arquivo csv
                StringBuilder cabecalho = new StringBuilder();
                cabecalho.Append("Data de Inclusão;");
                cabecalho.Append("Tipo de Tabela;");
                cabecalho.Append("Tabela;");
                cabecalho.Append("Codigo;");
                cabecalho.Append("TUSS;");
                cabecalho.Append("Descrição;");
                cabecalho.Append("Fabricante;");
                cabecalho.Append("Referência do Fabricante;");
                cabecalho.Append("Registro ANVISA;");
                cabecalho.Append("Classificação SIMPRO;");
                cabecalho.Append("Grupo Mat/Med;");
                cabecalho.Append("Grupo Estatístico;");
                cabecalho.Append("Autorização Prévia;");
                cabecalho.Append("Última Vigência;");
                cabecalho.Append("Valor;");
                cabecalho.Append("Prestador Tabela Própria;");

                Response.Write(cabecalho.ToString());
                Response.Write("\r");

                foreach (var item in listaItensMatMed)
                {
                    StringBuilder itens = new StringBuilder();
                    itens.Append(item.DataInclusao + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.TipoTabela + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Tabela + ";");
                    itens.Append("\t" + item.Codigo + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.TUSS + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Descricao + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.Fabricante + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.ReferenciaFabricante + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.RegistroAnvisa + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.ClassificacaoSimpro + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.GrupoMatMed + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.GrupoEstatistico + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.AutorizacaoPrevisa + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.UltimaVigencia + ";");
                    itens.Append("\t" + item.Valor + ";");
                    itens.Append(item.PrestadorTabelaPropria + ";");

                    Response.Write(itens.ToString());

                    Response.Write("\r");
                    //Response.Flush();
                }

                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "mensagem", "Final()", true);

                Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=relacao_materiais_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss") + ".csv");
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, não sei se entendi muito bem a sua pergunta.

Mas, ao carregar uma nova página, o documento atual é fechado e começa a carregar um novo documento. Qualquer código em seu documento atual não estará mais ativo quando a nova página começar a carregar.

Para conseguir disparar o alert quando a nova página carregar, você vai precisar inserir o código no documento da nova página ou então carregar está página em um iframe e ver quando ele é carregado no documento atual, assim irá conseguir disparar o alert.

Comment: Cara, é o seguinte. Tudo isso está feito. Pelo que eu li sobre o location, a página chamadora não fica em back, como você falou, mas sim a página chamada. Fiz a chamada pelo code behind, mas posso testar por js no momento em que o dom for montado. Coloquei a chamada no PageLoad. Isso não deu certo, mas a planilha é preenchida e tudo no PageLoad.

Comment: É que do modo que você parece precisar, seria necessário um callback a ser executado após rodar o location, porém isso não é possível, creio que por js resolverá o problema...

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Tem alguma idéia de co mo eu faço? Um luz por favor, que tô no osso.

Comment: Você só precisa que seja disparado o alert quando a página que gera o excel é aberta, certo?

Comment: Em realidade, o que eu preciso é que enquanto os dados do banco são carregados, preciso disparar um `loading`. Se o `loading` estiver  na página chamadora(ele fica visível) quando a página é chamada, ele para enquanto a página chamada é processada. Se eu coloco na página chamada(acredito ser o correto) ele não é mostrado. Quando tudo termina, aí vem o download da planilha.